# Conditional Expectation of Poisson Process?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Fix s,t such that s < t. If we are given that $N(t)=n$ then what is $\mathbb{E}[N(s)|N(t)=n]$? Intuitively I would imagine a uniform distribution so that $\mathbb{E}[N(s)|N(t)=n]=\frac{ns}{t}$ But is this correct? And if so, how would I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that given $N(t)  = n$, $N(s)$ can take only the values $0,1,...,n$, because $N$ has increasing paths. Now, for each $ 0 \leq k \leq n$ integer, $$P[N(s) = k | N(t) = n] = \frac{P(N(s) =k , N(t) = n)}{P(N(t) = n)} = P(N(s) = k) \frac{P(N(t) - N(s) = n-k)}{P(N(t) = n)}$$

where you know that $N(t) - N(s)$ is a Poisson random variable independent of $N(s)$ which is also Poisson. Thus one can calculate the above ratio.

Finally,
$$
\mathbb E[N(s) | N(t) = n] = \sum_{k=0}^n k P[N(s) = k | N(t) = n]
$$

so we can calculate this sum as well.

Comment: I can see that this is probably supposed to become a binomial distribution, but my maths are giving me $\binom{n}{k}s^kt^{-n}(t-s)^{n-k}$, which isn't quite right, is it?

Comment: Then you must show your maths : I will try to do it as well.

Comment: Isn't N(t)-N(s) not poisson at all but rather Skellam-distributed?

Comment: No, the point is that Nt is not independent of Ns. Check the properties of the Poisson process.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They would be totally independent if not for the fact that they are mutually overlapping (in fact superset/subset) intervals. I figured out the problem, by the way. $\binom{n}{k}s^kt^{-n}(t-s)^{n-k}$ is indeed correct, simply not sufficiently simplified. It becomes $\binom{n}{k}(\frac{s}{t})^k(1-\frac{s}{t})^{n-k}$

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Now of course, just taking the expectation gives you your answer of $\frac{ns}{t}$, right? Finally, also appreciate Joriki's answer, because his heuristic will help you in problems where computations are more difficult than here, because you will see an end to the computation, which will be your guide.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is right. This follows from the uniformity of the Poisson process: The distribution of the number of points in a subset $S$ of $[0,t]$ depends only on the measure of $S$, and, given the number of points in $[0,t]$, this is only compatible with the linearity of expectation if the expectation is proportional to the measure of $S$.

(If you want a more rigorous proof, this is straightforward if $\frac st$ is rational, since we can then divide $[0,t]$ into equal parts, some of which make up $[0,s]$. For $\frac st$ irrational, you might have to make a limit argument using countable additivity.)